# Content width for absolute positioned element in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, css-position, absolute

I'm working on some dropdown component and what I want to achieve is a button and when the user clicks on it there should appear a dropdown component.
The parent wrapper that contains the button and the dropdown component should have the button width and height. When the dropdown appears it has the parent width and it's wrong. 
I want to stretch it regarding children's width so the hardcoded width won't help as well.
I was thinking about *fit-content* but I'm not sure how it supports in the case of RN.

```
 <View style={{ width: 40, height: 40, backgroundColor: 'green' }}>
     // How to make its width based on max children width?
     <View style={{ backgroundColor: 'black', position: 'absolute', left: 50, top: -15 }}>
      <Text style={{color: 'white'}}>Item 1</Text>
      <Text style={{color: 'white'}} >Item long long 2</Text>
      <Text style={{color: 'white'}} >Item 3</Text>
      <Text style={{color: 'white'}} >Item long long4 2</Text>
     </View>
  </View>
```

Here is the [Example](https://snack.expo.io/@velidan/humiliated-donut)

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You could simply move the list outside and wrap both button and list inside a view and conditionally render the dropdown. This is how a sample component would look.

```
const CustomDropDown = () => {
  const [showItem,setShowItem]=useState(false);
  return (
     <View>
      <TouchableOpacity style={{ width: 40, height: 40, backgroundColor: 'green' }} 
      onPress={()=>{setShowItem(!showItem)}}>

      </TouchableOpacity>
      {
        showItem &&
        <View style={{ backgroundColor: 'black', position: 'absolute', left: 50, top: -15 }}>
          <Text style={{color: 'white'}}>Item 1</Text>
          <Text style={{color: 'white'}} >Item long long 2</Text>
          <Text style={{color: 'white'}} >Item 3</Text>
          <Text style={{color: 'white'}} >Item long long4 2</Text>
        </View>
      }
      </View>
  );
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Guruparan, I tried this solution but it doesn't work, unfortunately.
https://snack.expo.io/@velidan/sadistic-scone
Also, I'm using absolute layout calculation based on the Button position so it'd be perfect if the parent of dropdown would be in a container that has the same width& height as button (it works in this way in the case of web, at least)

Comment: it worked when i tried with your previous snack, this snack uses align center which is messing with the width

Comment: exactly, so what should we do if the dropdown container should be placed at the center?

Comment: So you want the drowndown to be on the center or should it be placed relative to the button ?

Comment: it should be placed relative to the button. But the button will be in some container. Eg, navigation item and this item will be positioned at the center =)

Comment: If its always going to be text you can use numberOfLines={1} in text component which seems to work